# What does "the most" in bold refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> We now spend the most and get the least. We spend ***among the
>   most***  for education and we’re 46th in education. We spend among
>   the most for prisons, and we are among the highest recidivism
>   rates …

What does "the most" in bold refer to?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that what is meant is simply

> "We are among the countries / states that spend the most"

That also explains the "46th", supposedly that is a referring to a ranking list between countries or states.

The whole sentence does give me a bit of a weird feeling anyway, because I would spend money **on** something, not **for** something.

Comment: I think the "for" is introducing "education" as a topic, not as an object of the verb. e.g. "For education, we are the highest spenders." But I agree with you it's a clumsy sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure that I get what this means either. It probably means that **"We spend, (among the largest of our expenditures), for education...."**. This seems most likely. It sounds like a slightly misspoken sentence.